# How to view or open Microsoft Windows 8 AMCache Registry Hive?

Tags: window, registry

I am learning about windows internals and its forensic technique when i came across all the tutorials people are speaking more about Amcache. When i searched over internet where its been mentioned as

> Amcahce is a small hive. Below is a view of the hive loaded in encase. There are only 4 keys under a 'Root' key. (Folders in the registry are called keys). The data of interest to us is located in the 'File' key. Files are grouped by their volume GUIDs. These are the same Volume GUIDs that you can find in the SYSTEM hive under MountedDevices and also under NTUSER.DAT MountPoints2.

i didn't understand how to proceed further and how to learn more about this

how to learn more about this HIVE file?
Is there any application to open such .hve files?

File located in : C:\Windows\appcompat\Programs\Amcache.hve

i have tried of opening such file by converting them to some binary files i didn't get any solutions.

Need any suggestions to open, understand such files and how such files help forensic people to know more about the past system functionalists such as recent changes made on the system.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, so I'm afraid your question is off-topc. Maybe people at https://superuser.com can help

Comment: Thanks for your words.. so how come i add superuser.com tag to this question  @JamesZ

Comment: I don't think you can tag or move your question. As far as I know, you need to delete this one and create a new one there.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to open Amcache.hve , but the easiest one is using Get-ForensicAmcache from powerforensics toolkit.

https://powerforensics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modulehelp/Get-ForensicAmcache/

Answer (score 0):

If you want a GUI tool to open Amcache.hve, I'll recommend you Registry explorer from Eric Zimmermann [Eric zimmermann tool's](https://ericzimmerman.github.io/#!index.md)